# How can I achieve this sound?

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, drumnbass

I would like to achieve the main neuro sound (1:07 in the video) of this track.

Any tips or tutorials?

Best,

Comment: I don't know what 'neuro' means, but there are two bass sounds happening, one sub sound, and one gritt sound; the sub is in like a 6/8 wobble and the gritt is in an 8/8 cycle, both start on the first off beat. Which do you mean?

Comment: neuro is a type of sound really organic and expressive used in neurofunk style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a relatively simple wobble and I'm sure there are a massive amount of different techniques for achieving this. I would start with a basic approach, that being the somewhat archaic technique of getting a "gabber" sound by distorting a long-tail 808 kick drum (I believe that is what wobbly baselines gradually evolved from).

More particulary - to achieve the sound you are going for, I would start with either an 808 bass sample, or a clean sine-wave synth patch tuned down a couple octaves to get a sub-bass sound then write the baseline. Next I would to add pitch and frequency modulation to my baseline then map both to a midi-knob or simply automate it. I would go easy on the pitch, maybe just a few semitones, but the modulation of the frequency and the pitch sound like they are in the same time. All of that would go through a distortion effect: this could be overdrive, gain, or saturation, or if you want it to sound more like a disgruntled robot voice you could even use a bit-crusher and down sample it.

Next I would make a copy of that. In order for it to sound good, the sub-bass needs to be separated from the distortion. For the copy of the baseline, turn off the distortion effect and cut off the frequencies that extend beyond the sub bass, usually around 60HZ. Also I would find a way to make the output of the sub bass mono so you only hear it in the center.

As for the original track with the distortion, do the opposite and roll off everything below 60HZ.

Ultimately - to keep the kick drum and the sub bass from washing each other out, I would throw a compressor on the track with the sub bass and run a side chain from the kick drum.

Comment: Any precise settings? Thx

Comment: Any settings will most likely be particular to the devices/FX you are using. Anything more precise than that would be along the lines of writing "that component of the song," not "how to achieve the sound." A good producer doesn't go out and bring a pre-tailored baseline to a composition. The baseline is created within the song.

Answer (score 1):

The bass sound under there is a slight hoover effect, the bass oscillators are slightly detuned and one of them is rough like a square wave or something with very wide frequencies...

they take that sound and put the filter on an LFO's and have other filters that are static and doing a bass cut with them... there is probably a slight postprocessing effect to enrich it even further and you can choose from any kind of slight delay echo overdrive of the millions available to fatten up a bit further.

the filters are very complex and you want get that mix in a hurry, but you can put the sound through a spectroscope and i GUARANTEE you that you will have a solid grasp of the frequencies that are being let through and the LFO frequencies. You will have trouble to find a synthesizer with that powerful filters, it's not a cheap one. there are at least 4 filters on that at the same time, but synths usually give you a mix of 3-10 filters all on the same control which are used as a single filter, so you need at least 2-3 complex ones for that effect.

the secret to complex sound is hoover oscillation large and small i.e. detune. detune makes an entire recording sound lofi oldschool natural rich organic non robotic complex characterful and interesting. not alot of synths give you control of detune cos nobody knows that.